# Make a list of all files in two folders then iterate through the combined list randomly

Tags: arrays, bash, random

I have two directories with photos that I want to manipulate to output a random order of the files each time a script is run. How would I create such a list?

```
d1=/home/Photos/*.jpg
d2=/mnt/JillsPC/home/Photos/*.jpg

# somehow make a combined list, files = d1 + d2
# somehow randomise the file order
# during execution of the for;do;done loop, no file should be repeated

for f in $files; do
    echo $f   # full path to each file
done
```

Comment: Just `files="$d1 $d2"`

Comment: Ok, I was hoping there would be a simple to combine the two lists, thanks. From there, how do I shuffle that list of files so that when I iterate through them, the order has been randomised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use variables if you don't have to. It's more natural if you chain a couple of commands together with pipes or [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). That way everything operates on streams of data without loading the entire list of names into memory all at once.

You can use `shuf` to randomly permute input lines, and `find` to list files one per line. Or, to be maximally safe, let's use `\0` separators. Finally, a [while loop with process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/how-can-i-read-line-by-line-from-a-variable-in-bash) reads line by line into a variable.

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file; do
    echo "$file"
done < <(find /home/Photos/ /mnt/JillsPC/home/Photos/ -name '*.jpg' -print0 | shuf -z)
```

That said, if you do want to use some variables then you should use arrays. Arrays handle file names with whitespace and other special characters correctly, whereas regular string variables muck them all up.

```
d1=(/home/Photos/*.jpg)
d2=(/mnt/JillsPC/home/Photos/*.jpg)
files=("${d1[@]}" "${d2[@]}")
```

Iterating in order would be easy:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Shuffling is tricky though. `shuf` is still the best tool but it works best on a stream of data. We can use `printf` to print each file name with the trailing `\0` we need to make `shuf -z` happy.

```
d1=(/home/Photos/*.jpg)
d2=(/mnt/JillsPC/home/Photos/*.jpg)
files=("${d1[@]}" "${d2[@]}")

while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file; do
    echo "$file"
done < <(printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | shuf -z)
```

Further reading:

1. [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
2. [How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)
3. [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)
4. [How can I randomize (shuffle) the order of lines in a file? Or select a random line from a file, or select a random file from a directory?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/026)

Comment: I find the `read -d $'\0' -r file` and `< <()` parts hard to follow, and I don't really get the significance of `\0`, but I see how cleanly this works. I experimented with selecting an item randomly from the array, then creating a temp array without the selected item, then reassigning the temp array back to the main array, then repeating that until the array was zero size (I guess that `shuf` does something like that anyway, selecting an item to one side then continuing, though much more efficiently of course); I did get that working also but your way is genius, so much better, many thanks!

Comment: I've added some links to relevant FAQs from [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) that explain in more detail why this code is so obtuse. Why use `while read` (see #1), why `-print0` and `-z` and `-d $'\0'` (see #2), why `< <()` (see #3).

Comment: Hi John, I came up with another possible solution that seems to work quite well; do you see any downsides to that approach?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution after some more reading:

```
files=(/home/roy/Photos/*.jpg /mnt/JillsPC/home/jill/Photos/*.jpg)
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" | sort -R
```

Edit: updated with John's improvements from comments.

- You can add any number of directories into an array declaration (though see caveat with complex names in comments).
- `sort -R` seems to use `shuf` internally from looking at it's `man` page.

This was the original, which works, but is not as robust as the above:

```
files=(/home/roy/Photos/*.jpg /mnt/JillsPC/home/jill/Photos/*.jpg)
(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${files[*]}") | sort -R
```

- With `IFS=$'\n'`, echoing the array will display it line by line (`IFS=$'somestring'` is syntax for string literals with escape sequences. So unlike `'\n'`, `$'\n'` is the correct way to set it to a line break). `IFS` is not needed when using the `printf` method above.
- `echo ${files[*]}` will print out all array elements at once, using the `IFS` defined in

Comment: This will work fine in practice. Since you asked for a critique, a few nitpicks...

Comment: Modifying `$IFS` is likely to mess up later commands. It's best to contain it to a subshell with `(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${files[@]}") | sort -R`. Or you can use `printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"`.

Comment: Files are legally allowed to have embedded newlines. It's pathological, but technically allowed. This is why I jumped through hoops to use NUL separators everywhere. Is it worth all the trouble? It depends how robust you want your script to be, I suppose. If I were writing something for personal use I wouldn't bother. But in a Stack Overflow answer that others might copy and paste I think it's worth showing the safest possible version.

Comment: `${files[*]}` will also mess up if a file has multiple spaces in a row; they'll be collapsed into a single space. Tabs and newlines will also be converted into spaces. The `printf` method doesn't have that problem.

Comment: All excellent points. I didn't know that newlines were allowed in filenames; that is indeed pathological and a bad design decision. Smart to contain `IFS` in a subshell like that, I'll use that whenever I use `IFS` then.  "The printf method doesn't have that problem.". So, by using `printf` instead of echo in the above and containing the `IFS` in a subshell should solve all possible issues?

Comment: No need to change `IFS` if you use `printf '%s\n'`.